# Validation of fields using context

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am developing a MVC asp.net web app where I have a view with several forms inside, each one  with its specific context, so many have the same name and the only way to make them different is using the context. I setup the events such as click, change, etc, with Jquery Context, everything works fine...

The problem appears when the client side validation paints the red color for the required fields in my view and all of its forms applying the "field-validation-error" class. 
When I enter the required fields contents of the second of my forms, the "Required." validation message that gets cleared is the first one, not the specific message error of the field inside its second form context.

My code looks like:
I have many controls with data annotations that use the Jquery context:

```
jQuery( expression, [context] )

$('#MyTextField', $('#my-form_context_1')) ;

$('#MyTextField', $('#my-form_context_2'));
```

Is there a way to work with JQuery context and apply validation in a specific context?

Answer (score 1):

With this [plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) it's possible to hook to form submit event. Thanks to that you are able to do whatever you want to validate your data.